# Kubernetes Multi-container communication

Tags: node.js, docker, kubernetes, azure-aks

I am having two docker containers of a node.js web application

1. Backend server
2. Front end , that depends on backend
   I tried hosting the containers using azure kubernetes service but was unable to connect them into a network.

Envionment.Prod.ts file of front end that needs backend connection:

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  domainURL: window.location.host,
  interfaceURL: 'http://52.224.xx.xx:3000/api/',
  assetURL: 'assets',
  name: 'prod'
};
```

as you can see my server listens on http://localhost_or_public_ip:3000/api/
and frontend container needs to connect to server.

Using AKS, public ip in cluster after deployment is allotted at run time , how can i configure this server ip into my frontend to make it listen on specific ip and port?

1. Is there a way to use localhost:port in kubernetes?
2. If not, can you please suggest a way to deploy my application ideal for production environment?

Note: Multi-container deployment is working fine on localhost docker environment and azure container instance

Using docker desktop for windows

I have been struggling over this issue for a while now it would helpful if someone can guide me for the solution!
Thanks for your views

Deployment.yaml file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: cspback
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: cspback
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: cspback
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        "beta.kubernetes.io/os": linux
      containers:
      - name: cspback
        image: [azure_registry].azurecr.io/backend:latest
        env:
        
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
      
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: cspback
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 3000
  selector:
    app: cspback
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: cspfront
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: cspfront
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 1
  minReadySeconds: 5 
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: cspfront
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        "beta.kubernetes.io/os": linux
      containers:
      - name: cspfront
        image: [azure_registry].azurecr.io/frontend:v1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 86
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 250m
          limits:
            cpu: 500m
       
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: secretupdate
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: cspfront
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 80
  selector:
    app: cspfront
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few try outs I was able to figure out the solution, Hope this helps people with similar use-case to work with:

I created a server service with type LoadBalancer in kubernetes deployment yaml file so that all the server pod requests will route through this cspbackserver-service, we need to set a static ip for  loadbalancer type.

Note: On Azure, if you want to use a user-specified public type loadBalancerIP, you first need to create a static type public IP address resource.
This solves the problem of assignment of new ips to kube pods every time we deploy the changes on AKS

Deployment.yaml file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: server-deployment
  labels:
    app: cspback
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: cspback
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: cspback
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: cspback
        image: __cspback__  
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
         
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: cspbackserver-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: cspbackend
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerIP: 10.0.171.239 //sample_ip
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 3000
      targetPort: 9457
      nodePort: 30008
```

Answer (score 0):

The k8s Service enables the frontend application to access the backend using a service name("cspback"). Set the interfaceURL to 'http://cspback/api/'

Add targetPort to the Service configuration

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: cspback
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 3000
  selector:
    app: cspback
```

In case if you are specific about using the port 3000 from frontend, update the port and interfaceURL with 3000.

for more details:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/

Comment: Were you able to resolve the issue?

Comment: Hi Null,Thank you for your response.                                                                                I was able to solve my problem using external type loadbalancer.                        Details are also mentioned in the link you provided  https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/